# New events with gtk+ (socket intercation with select)

Tags: c, sockets, select, gtk

I'm a real begginer in GTK+ programming, and I have trouble understanding the g_source_new() function.

I would like to handle my sockets using GTK events (new event when my socket is readable/writable, as using select).

If anybody could send me on a way, I'm completely lost...

PS: I don't want to use Gtk's socket management / creating a new thread for the UI.

Thank you by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSource is poorly documented. The best you can do is browse the source and see how the timer and idle sources are implemented. Read the code of g_timer_add and g_idle_add.

Comment: After hours of documentations, i finally managed how to use them. Reading g_timer_add helped me a lot. Thanks.